# setDirection GridWorld Greater than 360 degrees

Tags: java, location, gridworld

On the AP Quick Reference Code, it states "public `setDirection(int newDirection)` sets the direction of this actor to the angle between 0 and 359 degrees that is equivalent to newDirection"

However, in one of the released exam multiple choice questions, it states that you can set the direction by calling `setDirection(getDirection + RIGHT);`, however, what if the angle becomes greater or equal to 360 degrees? an example being 390 degrees.

Will this generate a run-time error, or will it just `%360` and get the correct reference angle?

Comment: The best way to get an answer to a question like this is to try it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to my question. Upon compiling the GridWorld Case Study, I can confirm that any integer value (so long as it is a valid integer) can work in the `setDirection(new Location);` method.